# html 5 canvas scratch plugin does not work on android

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to make a scratch lottery game, but it seems to break in android. I know it doesn't work in IE, I am just concerned with android. I am using the KinecticJS library.

```
(function () {

    var options = {
        scratchWidth: 200, // change scrathcher width here
        scratchHeight: 200, // change scrathcher height here
        scratcherSize:20, // change radius of scratcher
        imageHeight: 118,
        imageWidth: 106,
        imageUrl: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg',
    };

    function makeShapeComposite(shape, operation) {
        shape.attrs._sceneFunc = shape.attrs.sceneFunc;
        shape.attrs.sceneFunc = function (context) {
            context.save();
            context._context.globalCompositeOperation = operation;
            this.attrs._sceneFunc.call(this, context);
            context.restore();


        };
        return shape;
    };

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'scratcher',
        width: options['scratchWidth'],
        height: options['scratchHeight'] 
    });






    var imageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        var image = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 0, //change width of image here
            y: 0, //change width of image here
            image: imageObj,
            width: options['imageWidth'],
            height: options['imageHeight']
        });


        // add the shape to the layer
        imageLayer.add(image);


        // add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(imageLayer);
        imageLayer.setZIndex(0);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';


    var scratchLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var fill = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        fill: 'grey',
    });


    scratchLayer.add(fill);
    stage.add(scratchLayer);

 var clicking = false;

$('.kineticjs-content').on('mousedown touchstart',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clicking = true;
});  

$('.kineticjs-content').on('mouseup touchend',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clicking = false;
});


    $('.kineticjs-content').on('mousemove touchmove', function () {
        if(clicking == false) return;
        var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: mousePos.x,
            y: mousePos.y,
            radius: options['scratcherSize'],
            fill: 'red'
        });
        var pol = makeShapeComposite(circle, 'destination-out')
        scratchLayer.add(circle);
        scratchLayer.draw();
    });
})();
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dayly/r9r6J/)

Comment: what browser did you use in android

Comment: Both chrome and built in browser. Android 4.1.1. May be little bit slow. And I think viewport option in head need.